# Vertica database added duplicate entry with same primary key

Tags: vertica

I am running a docker image of `Vertica` on `windows`. I have created a table in `vertica` with this schema (`student_id` is `primary key`)

```
dbadmin@d1f942c8c1e0(*)=> \d testschema.student;
                                        List of Fields by Tables
   Schema   |  Table  |   Column   |    Type     | Size | Default | Not Null | Primary Key | Foreign Key
------------+---------+------------+-------------+------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------
 testschema | student | student_id | int         |    8 |         | t        | t           |
 testschema | student | name       | varchar(20) |   20 |         | f        | f           |
 testschema | student | major      | varchar(20) |   20 |         | f        | f           |
(3 rows)
```

`student_id` is a primary key. I am testing loading data from `csv` file using `copy` command.

First I used `insert` - `insert into testschema.student values (1,'Jack','Biology');`

Then I created a `csv` file at `/home/dbadmin/vertica_test` directory -

```
vi student.csv 
2,Kate,Sociology
3,Claire,English
4,Jack,Biology
5,Mike,Comp. Sci
```

Then I ran this command

```
copy testschema.students from '/home/dbadmin/vertica_test/student.csv' delimiter ',' rejected data as table students_rejected;
```

I tested the result

```
select * from testschema.student - shows 5 rows
select * from students_rejected; - no rows
```

Then I creates another `csv` file with bad data at `/home/dbadmin/vertica_test directory`

```
 vi student_bad.csv
bad_data_type_for_student_id,UnaddedStudent, UnaddedSubject
6,Cassey,Physical Education
```

I added data from bad `csv` file

```
copy testschema.students from '/home/dbadmin/vertica_test/student.csv' delimiter ',' rejected data as table students_rejected;
```

Then I tested the output

```
select * from testschema.student - shows 6 rows <-- only one row got added. all ok
select * from students_rejected; - shows 1 row  <-- bad row's entry is here. all ok
```

all looks good

Then I added the bad data again without the rejected data option

```
copy testschema.students from '/home/dbadmin/vertica_test/student_bad.csv' delimiter ',' ;
```

But now the entry with student id 6 got added again!!

```
student_id |  name  |       major
------------+--------+--------------------
          1 | Jack   | Biology
          2 | Kate   | Sociology
          3 | Claire | English
          4 | Jack   | Biology
          5 | Mike   | Comp. Sci
          6 | Cassey | Physical Education <--
          6 | Cassey | Physical Education <--
```

Shouldn't this have got rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created your `students` with a command of this type:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE students (
  student_id int 
, name       varchar(20)
, major      varchar(20)
, CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY(student_id)                                                                                                                                         
);
```

that is, without the explicit keyword `ENABLED`, then the primary key constraint is disabled. That is, you can happily insert duplicates, but will run into an error if you later want to join to the `students` table via the primary key column.

With the primary key constraint enabled ...

```
[...]
, CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY(student_id) ENABLED                                                                                                                                         
[...]
```

I think you get the desired effect.

The whole scenario:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS students;
CREATE TABLE students (
  student_id int
, name       varchar(20)
, major      varchar(20)
, CONSTRAINT pk_students PRIMARY KEY(student_id) ENABLED
);

INSERT INTO students
          SELECT 1,'Jack'  ,'Biology'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Kate'  ,'Sociology'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Claire','English'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Jack'  ,'Biology'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Mike'  ,'Comp. Sci'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'Cassey','Physical Education'
;
-- out  OUTPUT 
-- out --------
-- out       6

COMMIT;

COPY students FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','
REJECTED DATA AS TABLE students_rejected;
6,Cassey,Physical Education
\.
-- out vsql:/home/gessnerm/._vfv.sql:4: ERROR 6745:  
-- out  Duplicate key values: 'student_id=6' 
-- out  -- violates constraint 'dbadmin.students.pk_students'
SELECT * FROM students;
-- out  student_id |  name  |       major        
-- out ------------+--------+--------------------
-- out           1 | Jack   | Biology
-- out           2 | Kate   | Sociology
-- out           3 | Claire | English
-- out           4 | Jack   | Biology
-- out           5 | Mike   | Comp. Sci
-- out           6 | Cassey | Physical Education
SELECT * FROM students_rejected;
-- out  node_name | file_name | session_id | transaction_id | statement_id | batch_number | row_number | rejected_data | rejected_data_orig_length | rejected_reason 
-- out -----------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------
-- out (0 rows)
```

And the only reliable check seems to be the `ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS()` call ...

```
ALTER TABLE students ALTER CONSTRAINT pk_students DISABLED;
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 7.618 ms. All rows formatted: 7.632 ms
COPY students FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','
REJECTED DATA AS TABLE students_rejected;
6,Cassey,Physical Education
\.
-- out Time: First fetch (0 rows): 31.790 ms. All rows formatted: 31.791 ms

SELECT * FROM students;
-- out  student_id |  name  |       major        
-- out ------------+--------+--------------------
-- out           1 | Jack   | Biology
-- out           2 | Kate   | Sociology
-- out           3 | Claire | English
-- out           4 | Jack   | Biology
-- out           5 | Mike   | Comp. Sci
-- out           6 | Cassey | Physical Education
-- out           6 | Cassey | Physical Education
SELECT * FROM students_rejected;
-- out  node_name | file_name | session_id | transaction_id | statement_id | batch_number | row_number | rejected_data | rejected_data_orig_length | rejected_reason 
-- out -----------+-----------+------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+------------+---------------+---------------------------+-----------------
-- out (0 rows)
SELECT ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS('students');
-- out  Schema Name | Table Name | Column Names | Constraint Name | Constraint Type | Column Values 
-- out -------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------
-- out  dbadmin     | students   | student_id   | pk_students     | PRIMARY         | ('6')
-- out (1 row)
```

Comment: I created table like `create table ...  student_id int primary key, ...`. When now I try to add constraint `alter table testschema.student add constraint student_id_pk primary key (student_id) enabled;` then I get err `Primary constraint for relation "student" already exists`. What is the way to enable the constraint if I have not explicitly created the constraint.

Comment: Run:
`SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','testschema.students',FALSE);`
You will see an `ADD CONSTRAINT ..` command, in which you will find the name of the constraint - which will probably be `C_PRIMARY` by default.
Then, go (if the name is what I think):
`ALTER TABLE students ALTER CONSTRAINT C_PRIMARY ENABLED;`
Or: `ALTER TABLE students DROP PRIMARY KEY;`, followed. by your command, will do the trick, too.